# Override Ascending Descending functions - ui-grid

Tags: angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I'm using grid view for my reporting view. I need to override functions on `Sort Ascending` and `Sort Descending` event.

[image]

Here is my code for **gridOptions**.

```
var dynamicColumnDefs = _.map(_.keys(res[0]), function (key) {
 return {name: key, field: key, width: '10%', enableHiding: false};
});
 console.log('columnDefs', dynamicColumnDefs);
 scope.gridOptions = {
  data: res,
  enableColumnResize: true,
  enableGridMenu: true,
  exporterMenuPdf: false,
  columnDefs: dynamicColumnDefs,
  enableHorizontalScrollbar: 2,
  enableVerticalScrollbar: 2,
  onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
   // I hope I need to overide my function here
 }
};
```

I need to trigger the event once I click `Ascending` and `Descending` only. How can I do it. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I can do that;

```
scope.gridOptions = {
 data: res,
 enableColumnResize: true,
 enableGridMenu: true,
 exporterMenuPdf: false,
 columnDefs: dynamicColumnDefs,
 enableHorizontalScrollbar: 2,
 enableVerticalScrollbar: 2,
 onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
  scope.gridApi = gridApi;
  scope.gridApi.core.on.sortChanged(scope, scope.sortChange);
  sortChanged(scope.gridApi.grid, [scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[1]]);
 }
};

sortChanged = function (grid, sortColumns) {
// Do Whatever I want
}
```